# How do I avoid ambiguous step definitions in Cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, cucumber, bdd

I'm running into ambiguous step definition errors. The following scenarios live in different feature files, and have one identical step: `Then I should see my profile page`. How do I avoid this from happening?

```
# authentication.feature
Scenario: Successful sign in
  Given I visit the sign in page
  When I submit valid sign in information
  Then I should see my profile page

# signing_up.feature
Scenario: Successful sign up
  Given I visit the sign up page
  When I submit valid information
  Then I should see my profile page

# authentication_steps.rb
...
Then /^I should see my profile page$/ do
  page.current_path.should == user_path(@user)
end

# signing_up.feature
...
Then /^I should see my profile page$/ do
  page.current_path.should == user_path(@user)
end
```

I'm running into this problem with error messages too:

```
Scenario: Unsuccessful sign up
  ...
  Then I should see an error message

Scenario: Unsuccessful login
  ...
  Then I should see an error message
```

Comment: please show those step definition. If they are the same you just need to have one. If they do diferent stuff then they should have different names

Comment: @IsmaelAbreu, I added the step definitions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not stay only with the one in authentication_steps.rb ? I think you can use all steps in any feature file

Comment: Ismael is right, there's no need to duplicate your step definition. You should group steps with the semantics as criteria. He's also right you can use any step in any scenario.

Comment: I figured it out. The only thing is, my step definition of `I should see my profile page` depends on an instance variable. It's looking a little messy. I there a way to pass it an object so I can reference it as a local variable instance of having it depend on having an `@user` to work?

Comment: Yes, you could have a route /my_profile that redirects to the signed in user profile page. Or you could specify arguments in those steps.

Comment: `When I submit valid information with username: "someusername"`

Comment: `Then I should see profile page of: "someusername"` and this might come handy in other features